# Coderbyte Challenge: Questions Marks - RegExp pattern '/d(\?\?\?)d/gi' incorect

Tags: javascript, regex

I was solving the [Coderbyte Challenge - Questions Marks](https://coderbyte.com/information/Questions%20Marks)
When I run my code in the browser it all works fine, however, once I run it on the coderbyte website it throws an error.

**The Challenge is:**

> Have the function QuestionsMarks(str) take the str string parameter,
> which will contain single digit numbers, letters, and question marks,
> and check if there are exactly 3 question marks between every pair of
> two numbers that add up to 10. If so, then your program should return
> the string true, otherwise it should return the string false. If there
> aren't any two numbers that add up to 10 in the string, then your
> program should return false as well.
>
> For example: if str is "arrb6???4xxbl5???eee5" then your program
> should return true because there are exactly 3 question marks between
> 6 and 4, and 3 question marks between 5 and 5 at the end of the
> string.
>
> Use the Parameter Testing feature in the box below to test your code
> with different arguments.

**Test Cases Are:**

> "arrb6???4xxbl5???eee5"     **true**
>
> "aa6?9"       **false**
>
> "acc?7??sss?3rr1??????5"    **true**

My solution to this was to use RegExp to solve the challenge. the code below works well when I run it in the Browser, however, Coderbyte console throws an error every time:

> /tmp/009904362/main.js:11 clean = clean.match(/d(???)d/gi);               ^SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /d(???)d/

**Here is my code -**

```
function QuestionsMarks(str) { 

//create a "clean" array containing only the numbers and question marks from str
  var result;
  let clean = str.match(/[0-9?]/g);
// join() the array back in to the string
  clean = clean.join("");     

// use match() to return an array of pairs that match the pattern d???d  
 clean = clean.match(/d(\?\?\?)d/gi);
 
//create a function sumCheck() that converts first and last char of every array string to Number and checks if the sum of digits is 10
//using forEach() run the sumcheck() on all strings in the array
 clean.forEach(sumCheck);

 function sumCheck(string){
        if((Number(string.charAt(0)) + Number(string.charAt(string.length - 1)))  == 10){
                result = true;
        }else{
            result = false;
        }
 }
    return result;
  }
QuestionsMarks("acc?7??sss?3rr1??????5");
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is causing the error, from the error message it looks like the slashes are removed from the expression, in any case, your pattern is incorrect, to match numbers you need to use `\d` not just `d`. Try `new RegExp("\\d(\\?\\?\\?)\\d")`

Comment: Don't know what's causing the error. I don't think it should be giving this error. Anyhow, try doing something like `/\d([?][?][?])\d/`, see if it works (it's an ugly hack).

Comment: The pattern `\\d(\\?\\?\\?)\\d` is not going to work, it won't work for the third case where the second and third question mark are separated by characters.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness: The string is cleaned from letters before testing the pattern.

Comment: Yeah that could be one way of doing it, seems a bit unnecessary though.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness: it's the way used in the question.

Comment: Your point being? If there's a better solution, why not provide it?

Comment: @Titus just tried `/\\d(\\?\\?\\?)\\d/gi` and it worked well. It seems that the console is removing the slashes as you said. Thanks again !

Comment: @Denzelzeldi: as an aside, even with the "corrected" pattern, your approach is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to come from Coderbyte that isn't able to parse correctly escaped characters in regex patterns (literals or with the RegExp constructor). So the simplest solution is to replace escaped sequences: `\d` => `[0-9]`, and `\?` => `[?]` (as suggested by @Saud in comments).

---

About your approach:

> ... check if there are exactly 3 question marks between **every** pair of two numbers that add up to 10 ...

What does your corrected pattern `/[0-9][?]{3}[0-9]/g`?
It looks for digits separated by three question marks (and then you check if the sum of two digits is 10). Even if this pattern would be able to find all pair of digits separated by three question marks in the string (that isn't the case<sup>(*)</sup>), It doesn't check if there are digits that add up to 10 and that aren't separated by exactly 3 question marks!

So, the goal is to find if the string contains a pair of digits that add up to 10 **without** the 3 question marks. If this pair exists the function returns `false`.

---

(*): Why `/[0-9][?]{3}[0-9]/g` isn't able to find all pair of digits separated by 3 question marks?

Example with: [1???2???3???4](https://regex101.com/r/Uu9dVp/1)
Because you can't match the same character twice. The pattern will find: `1???2` and `3???4` but not `2???3` since the `2` is already consumed by the first match.

---

A possible way to do it:

```
function QuestionsMarks(str) {
    var state = { d1: 0, d2: 0, marks: 0,
        init: function() { this.d1 = this.d2; this.marks = 0; },
        check: function() { return this.d1 + this.d2 > 9 && this.marks != 3; }
    };  
    var re = /[0-9?]/g;
    var m;

    while ( (m = re.exec(str)) !== null ) {
        if ( m[0] == '?' ) {
            state.marks++;
        } else {
            state.d2 = parseInt(m[0]);
            if ( state.check() ) return false;
            state.init();  
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```